# Numpy Masking and Meshgrid giving confusing output

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use numpy.meshgrid to simulate a 3D space, and preform a few action in it. First I need to define a subspace in it using some sort of mask, and later on I will need to calculate a variety of distances between different points.

```
def Projtest1(LX,LY,LZ,N,R):
    xlin,dx=np.linspace(-LX/2,LX/2,N,retstep=True,dtype=float)
    ylin,dy=np.linspace(-LY/2,LY/2,N,retstep=True,dtype=float)
    zlin,dz=np.linspace(-LZ/2,LZ/2,N,retstep=True,dtype=float)

    X,Y,Z=np.meshgrid(xlin,ylin,zlin,indexing='ij')

    mask=(X)**2+(Y)**2+(Z)**2
    Cmask=mask<R**2
    Cmask=Cmask.astype(int,'copy=False')
    XC=X
    XC=np.multiply(X,Cmask)
    YC=np.multiply(Y,np.where(False,Y,Cmask.astype(int)))
    ZC=np.multiply(Z,np.where(False,Z,Cmask.astype(int)))


    print (np.shape(XC))    
    print (np.shape(Cmask))
    print(X[2][2][2]*Cmask,Cmask[2][2][2],X[2][2][2])
    return Cmask, XC, X # YC, ZC
```

One of my issues is that when I run this code, I only get a part of the space that I want, on any given matrix XC YC ZC.

```
Projtest1(100,100,100,5,50)
```

Cmask

```
(array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

and XC what should be the masked X coord for the subspace

```
array([[[ -0.,  -0.,  -0.,  -0.,  -0.],
     [ -0.,  -0.,  -0.,  -0.,  -0.],
     [ -0.,  -0.,  -0.,  -0.,  -0.],
     [ -0.,  -0.,  -0.,  -0.,  -0.],
     [ -0.,  -0.,  -0.,  -0.,  -0.]],

    [[ -0.,  -0.,  -0.,  -0.,  -0.],
     [ -0., -25., -25., -25.,  -0.],
     [ -0., -25., -25., -25.,  -0.],
     [ -0., -25., -25., -25.,  -0.],
     [ -0.,  -0.,  -0.,  -0.,  -0.]],

    [[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
     [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
     [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
     [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
     [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]],

    [[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
     [  0.,  25.,  25.,  25.,   0.],
     [  0.,  25.,  25.,  25.,   0.],
     [  0.,  25.,  25.,  25.,   0.],
     [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]],

    [[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
     [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
     [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
     [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
     [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]]]))
```

I am confused by this, and am not sure if it is some sort of indexing mismatch, or perhaps a type error. I am quite novice at using numpy, and am wondering if meshgrid is the wrong approach for my purposes. The code is a little mangled from swapping out parts to try and see what is really going on

Any and all input would be helpful, and let me know I I need to provide any additional info. Thanks!

EDIT: I would like the XC array, shown second, to carry through values in all the positions that the Cmask Array, shown first, is =1 (or True, if it is better as bool). You can see that on the 3rd slice of the XC matrix, which corrosponds to the X=0 plane, there are no values carried, despite the mask being positive there. This problem occurs also in YC and ZC.

Comment: Consider posting the error message, it would make is that much easier to spot the problem.

Comment: Also, provide the expected output and the logic behind this, since it is difficult to know why the result you get is not satisfactory.

Comment: My apologies, there was no error message, it simply outputs this.
The logic I was intending is that all of the X values within the masked array would carry over. Where they do not is seen in the 3rd slice of the last array, displaying all zeroes along that matrix. 

The masked X value does not include the origin, nor any on that XC=0 slice.
Similarly the YC shows gaps at the origin, and the y=0 line, where the ZC array also lets through values, while itself excluding YC and XC values.

Thanks for the replies, and let me know if that is unclear.

Comment: If you print out `X` before you do all the masking, you will see that also there the central slide is zeros. This is also the expected behaviour, because you defined `X` (and `xlin`) to be zero in the center. The rest now is wild guessing, but did you maybe want to work with your `mask` variable, i.e. the distance of each point from the center?

Comment: Now that I've read your responce, and checked what I think I need, I'm not sure there was a problem at all with the outputs, and that I had confused myself quite thoroughly. Thank you, and this is rather embarrassing.

A question that likely led down this path, is; Is there an effective way to remove all of those entries outside the masked space? Such that if I wanted to choose random values from the XC,YC, and ZC It would only have to choose acceptable values. I remember that this problem is what got me spiralling from the presences of zeros within the Cmasked coords.

Thank you again

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, but you could try something along the line `idx=random.choice(list(zip(*np.where(mask<R**2))))` and then get your x, y, and z values with `X[idx]`, `Y[idx]`, and `Z[idx]`, respectively. Here the `choice` function is the one from the actual `random` module, not `np.random`.